# Differentiation of Linear Regression function

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, differentiation

I am getting started on the caltech Machine learning course. In the linear regression video to minimize the error differentiation is performed, i did understand the power rule of differentiation however in the second step i did not understand how did X get converted to X'(X Transpose).
Is it because we of vector multiplication rule as column of X and resulting (Xw-y) row needs to match? Any pointers would be of great help.
[image]
Thank you

Comment: Lookup "derivation of the Normal Equation in Linear Algebra". Maybe this page can help: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/derivation-of-the-normal-equation-for-linear-regression, but there are many other pages that may better fit your reading style